# How can i update another model's data before save of one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am making a wallet application in rails. I don't know how can i update balance field in user model before insertion of a new record in transaction.
When user is sending money `user_id` is taken from hidden field and email has to be entered of receiver and `user_id`,`user_email`,`amount` is stored in transaction table.
How to deduct money from one record and add to another. Can i use sql update to do that?

This is user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     has_many :transactions
end
```

**This is user table balance in included in this field.**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "email"    
 t.string   "encrypted_password"   
 t.string   "reset_password_token"
 t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
 t.datetime "remember_created_at"
 t.integer  "sign_in_count"        
 t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
 t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
 t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
 t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
 t.datetime "created_at"                         
 t.datetime "updated_at"                      
 t.string   "Firstname"            
 t.string   "Lastname"               
 t.date     "Dob"
t.integer  "Balance"
```

end

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord

     belongs_to :user
end
```

**This is Transaction table. User_id is for sender and user_email is for receiver**

```
create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "user_email"
  t.integer  "amount"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code. For creating transaction from user call

```
current_user.transaction.new(transaction_params)
```

Now in model transaction.rb file

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :check_and_update_balance

  def check_and_update_balance
    ## since user or sender is already there no need of sender
    receiver = User.find_by(email: user_email)
    if user.has_sufficient_balance?(amount) and receiver.present?
       user.update_attributes(balance: balance - amount)
       receiver.update_attributes(balance: balance + amount)    
    end
  end
end
```

HOPE this Helps !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `before_save` callback:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :do_something_transaction

  def do_something_transaction
    #here you update your transanction
  end

end
```

Comment: yes.. I have got that but how to fetch balance of two user and perform subtraction and addition that i m not able to figure out.

Comment: That is more related with business logic, maybe you need to post another question with the rule that you want to implement in you `before_save` method.. so we can help you with that. If this answer is satisfactory please accept it (Click the checkmark under this post)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch balances of both sender and receiver like so:

```
@sender = User.find_by(id: user_id)
@receiver = User.find_by(email: user_email)
```

And to change balances use ActiveRecord `update`:

```
if @sender.has_sufficient_balance?(amount) # make sure sender has sufficient balance first!
  @sender.update(balance: @sender.balance - amount)
  @receiver.update(balance: @receiver.balance + amount)
end
```

You can use a `before_save` callback as Alejandro Montilla suggested to do this.

Also, use `decimal` data type for `amount` and `balance` instead of `integer`

Comment: i am getting and error in this code.   
syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ':'
 @receiver.update(balance: balance + amount)

Comment: @KaushikDas try this: `@sender.update(balance: @sender.balance - amount)` and `@receiver.update(balance: @receiver.balance + amount)`

Comment: Yes i did the same in different way... Figured it out... :)